# How to compare two arrays and get matching output?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

In my collection I have a `category` array as below.

[image]

I receive another array to my API like below

```
array = ['Chess','Rugby'];
```

I want to add a condition to my database query such that `catName` field from `category` objects exists in `array`.

currently I'm using the below code to get the results:

```
postSchemaModel.aggregate([{
            "$geoNear": {
                "near": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [parseFloat(long), parseFloat(lat), ] },
                "distanceField": "dist.calculated",
                "maxDistance": parseInt(maxDistance),
                "includeLocs": "dist.location",
                "spherical": true
            }
        },
        { "$match": { "$or": [{ "typology": "post" }, { "typology": "chat_group" }] } },
        {
            "$match": {
                "createdAt": {
                    "$gte": '2020-07-15 23:54:38.673665',
                    "$lt": '2020-06-15 23:54:38.673665'
                }
            }
        },
        { "$limit": limit },
        { "$skip": startIndex },
        { "$sort": { "createdAt": -1 } },
        {
            "$lookup": {
                "from": userSchemaModel.collection.name,
                "localField": "user_id",
                "foreignField": "_id",
                "as": "user_id"
            }
        },
        {
            "$project": {
                "post_data": 1,
                "likes": 1,
                "commentsCount": 1,
                "post_img": 1,
                "isUserLiked": 1,
                "usersLiked": 1,
                'exp_date': 1,
                "has_img": 1,
                "user_id": {
                    "img": "$user_id.img",
                    "_id": "$user_id._id",
                    "user_name": "$user_id.user_name",
                    "bday": "$user_id.bday",
                    "imagesource": "$user_id.imagesource",
                    "fb_url": "$user_id.fb_url",
                },
                "typology": 1,
                "geometry": 1,
                "category": 1,
                "created": 1,
                "createdAt": 1,
                "updatedAt": 1,
            }
        },
    ]).then(async function(posts) {
        //some code here
        }
    });
```

> *UPDATE : Sample Output*

```
{
            "_id": "5f0bd1b7d6ed4f0017e5177c",
            "post_data": "bitch boy sudesh",
            "likes": 2,
            "commentsCount": 1,
            "post_img": null,
            "isUserLiked": true,
            "usersLiked": [
                "5f0bfa296ee76f0017f13787",
                "5ef60bba10e9090017e2c935"
            ],
            "exp_date": "2020-07-16T00:00:00.000Z",
            "has_img": false,
            "user_id": [
                {
                    "img": [
                        "default-user-profile-image.png"
                    ],
                    "_id": [
                        "5ef9a7a2922eba0017ce47e0"
                    ],
                    "user_name": [
                        "Sudesh"
                    ],
                    "bday": [
                        "1997-05-02T00:00:00.000Z"
                    ],
                    "imagesource": [
                        "fb"
                    ],
                    "fb_url": [
                        "https://platform-lookaside.fbsbx.com/platform/profilepic/?asid=1846836948784193&width=400&ext=1596011605&hash=AeRsB0QJQH7edpRT"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "typology": "post",
            "geometry": {
                "pintype": "Point",
                "_id": "5f0bd1b7d6ed4f0017e5177d",
                "coordinates": [
                    79.9200017,
                    6.7088167
                ]
            },
            "category": [
                {
                    "_id": "5f0bd1b7d6ed4f0017e5177e",
                    "catID": "5eef80cc5de48230887f3aa8",
                    "catName": "Chess"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5f0bd1b7d6ed4f0017e5177e",
                    "catID": "5eef80cc5de48230887f3aa8",
                    "catName": "Rugby"
                }
            ],
            "created": 1594610103626,
            "createdAt": "2020-07-13T03:15:03.629Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-07-18T14:02:35.080Z"
        }
```

Comment: `category` is an array of objects. `array` in your example is an array of strings. Can you give an example of the result array?

Comment: @Yos Added a sample result I'm currently getting

Comment: You're saying "I am receiving another array to my API like below

`array = ['category1','category2','category3'];`" What is the connection between `array` and `category`?

Comment: @Yos In my `postSchemaModel` here it has an array "category". I want to check If that array contains any of the elements in `array = ['Chess','Rugby' ];` and take them to my output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using another `$match` with `"$elemMatch"` solved the problem

```
"$match": {
                    "category": { "$elemMatch": { "catName": "Rugby", "catName": "Carrom" } },
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method if you only want to get `true`/`false` result:

```js
category.some(element => array.includes(element.catName))
```

If you want to get an array of all the `category` objects with cat names that also exist in the `array` then you can [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method:

```js
category.filter(element => array.includes(element.catName))
```

If you have an object called `array` in your code and you want to find at array of categories where cat names are in the `array` then you can add the condition to your `$match` stage:

```js
  { "$match": { "$or": [{ "typology": "post" }, { "typology": "chat_group" }] }, "category.catName": { $in: array } }
```

Comment: Thanks !. But can you suggest me how to use this in **aggregate pipeline above**

Comment: You need to be more specific in your question, you didn't mention the last condition. Also it's not clear where/what is `array` in your database/API response.